# How to pull XCOM value from on_failure_callback

Tags: airflow

When a **task** fails, is it possible to pull a **XCOM** value that has been previously set in an other **task** during the **on_failure_callback** execution?

To be more specific, exemple:

```
dag: task1 >> task2
```

- **task1** runs successfully and set `key="test"` `value=123` in **Xcom**
- **task2** fails
- **on_failure_callback** is called

Is this possible to retrieve the value of key `test` in the **on_failure_callback** ?

I tried like this, but it seems it didn't find any value:

```py
# Daf configuration
    ...
    "on_failure_callback": deploy_failure,
    ...

# In task1
    kwargs["ti"].xcom_push(key="test", value=123)

# on_failure_callback method
def deploy_failure(context):
    print("/!\ Deploy failure callback triggered...")
    test_value = context.get("ti").xcom_pull(key="test")
    print(test_value)
```

**test_value** is `None`

I am sure the Xcom value is set because I can see it on the **Airflow** backend.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess there is some issue with `provide_context` in the failure_callback. You can work around this by accessing directly XCom class:

```
from airflow.models import XCom

def deploy_failure(context):
    print("/!\ Deploy failure callback triggered...")
    test_value = XCom.get_one(execution_date = context.get('execution_date'), key='test')
    print("ALERT: {0}".format(test_value))
```

Comment: Did work!! But how to test(mock XCom, for example) ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to pull the XCOM value directly using the following code. It seems like whatever issue you were facing got fixed.

```
def task_failure_alert(context):
     ti = context['ti']

     test_value = ti.xcom_pull(key="test")
```